# Tomcat6 and Audited Objects on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat6

Trying to use [Audited Objects](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audited-objects/) in order to port a make process we've been running, I get a failure when starting the servlet instance. This is also the reason I ask this on StackOverflow and not on one of the other SE sites, as this relates to a tool for developers.

I copied the file `AO.war` to `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps` and when restarting Tomcat it gets automatically unpacked into a folder `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/AO`. But whenever I attempt to start the instance (that is shown properly in the Tomcat manager), I get this:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /AO could not be started
```

The log file gives me:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.aotool.web.listener.SessionListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aotool.web.listener.SessionListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3915)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1251)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:613)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Mar 28, 2012 11:47:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
```

I am not a Tomcat or Java developer, only a mere user of Tomcat. Previously I tried to use the `aoserver` and `aoserver.cfg` (adjusted to correct paths and ownership) method described [here](http://audited-objects.sourceforge.net/html/man/ao-install.html), but that fails silently without giving any clues.

Note: I gave ownership to `/etc/tomcat6` (and files underneath) to the `tomcat6` user as which Tomcat is running.

Running version of Tomcat is: `6.0.24-2ubuntu1.10`

Comment: You should probably not give ownership of the `/etc/tomcat6` directory to the `tomcat6` user -- if the Tomcat server is hacked, you want as little as possible to be writable -- ideally nothing that could re-infect the server across a restart.

Comment: @sarnold: I realize that. But: a.) this is a development machine in an intranet and b.) if the problem has been resolved I am more than willing to tighten security again.

Comment: I do not know AO but the obvious seems that the jar containing the class `com.aotool.web.listener.SessionListener` is missing in the WEB-INF/lib of AO.war, or that the class itself is missing in WEB-INF/classes. Can you unzip the war and check?

Comment: @BGR: will do and will amend the question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the server and try completely removing the webapps/AO directory.

Check that the AO.war file size is as expected before restarting.

Comment: The `AO.war` is 14.04 MiB. When starting Tomcat6, the `AO/` folder is 15.11 MiB. This doesn't change anything though and I have tried that before, after discovering that it extracts the file automatically. The MD5 of the `.war` file is `b09203ce866059ff0a04e56ad2202db1`, which should be the one from `audited-objects-AO-1.0.10.zip`.